# Setting Data in new Array to Map (React/Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have data coming back from the db like so:

```
[{"id":"a7e45e4c-4af1-477e-9642-759fff49d44e","name":"Gallons","unitSize":[50,5,25]},
{"id":"5c607a2c-9388-4c09-a0dc-c6cd1d35a9c9","name":"lbs","unitSize":[30,90,60]}],
"errors":null}]
```

I have two dropdowns, one maps the Units of Measure (name) and its working great, I now want to create a new list for the second dropdown, which returns only the Unit Sizes (unitSize) for the selected Units Of Measure. The problem I am having is that react wont let me map through my list. Here is what it says:

[image]

**UPDATE** In my code, within the renderUnitSize function, my uosArr which is holding the specific data i want is working correctly, this is where I am now trying to set the data into uosList. Howeve I console.log it after I setState and my uoslist is empty. It is an array, however I am assuming this error is coming because its not holding any data?

[image]

```
public state = {
    uosList: [],
};

public returnUnitSizes = () => {
    const product = this.state.product;
    const uom = product.unit;
    const uosArr = this.state.unitOfMeasures.find(um => um.name === uom);
    this.setState({
        uosList: uosArr
    });
    console.log();
}

  public handleUOMChange(event: any) {
    const product = this.state.product;
    product.unit = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
        product
    }, () =>  this.returnUnitSizes());
    console.log(product);
}

       <FormGroup className="required">
       <Label>Unit of Measure</Label>
        <EInput
        type="select"
         name="unitOfMeasure"
         id="unitOfMeasure"
         value={this.state.product.unit}
         onChange={this.handleUOMChange}
         required={true}
         >
         <option />
            {this.state.unitOfMeasures.map((UOM: IUnitOfMeasure, 
          index: number) =>
         <option key={UOM.id} value={UOM.name}>{UOM.name} 
            </option>
          )}
        </EInput>
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup className="required">
        <Label>Unit Size</Label>
          <EInput
            type="select"
            name="unitOfMeasure"
            value={this.state.product.size}
            onChange={this.handleUnitSizeChange}
            disabled={this.state.unitOfMeasure.id !== ''}
            required={true}
        >
        <option />
        {this.state.uosList && this.state.uosList.map((uosList: any, index: number) =>
        <option key={index} value={uosList[index]}>{uosList}</option>
                                    )
                                }
                            </EInput>
                        </FormGroup>
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `this.state.uosList`? That error is happening because when you are calling `map`, `this.state.uosList` is not an array.

Comment: I did not! Thanks for the insight, I did that and it looks like it is an array, however the array doesnt havent anything in it so my list is not getting set in there properly.

Comment: just posted an update, looks like it is an array however its coming back empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistakes lies in this function:

```js
public returnUnitSizes = () => {
    const product = this.state.product;
    const uom = product.unit;
    const uosArr = this.state.unitOfMeasures.find(um => um.name === uom);
    this.setState({
        uosList: uosArr
    });
    console.log();
}
```

You are setting `uosList` to `uosArr`. But `uosArr` refers to an element of the array `this.state.unitOfMeasures`. As you wrote, this is an `object` with the shape:

```js
{
  id: string,
  name: string,
  unitSize: Array,
}
```

In reality you want to set `uosList` to `uosArr.unitSize`.